# How to calculate the similarity between two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, similarity, data-wrangling

Right now, I'd like to calculate the column name similarity (e.g., jaro distance) between two columns on the database.

Here's the condition:

- There are 3 tables (i.e., T1, T2, T3) and each table has 3 columns (i.e., C1, C2, and C3).
- Then, we can denote T1C1, T1C2, T1C3, T2C1, ...., T3C3.

I want to calculate the similarity between the two columns. However, what I expect is (T1 is only compared with T2,T3; T2 is only compared with T1,T3, and T3 is only compared with T1,T2).
For example:

- sim(T1C1, **T2C1**), sim(T1C1, **T2C2**), sim(T1C3,**T2C3**)
- sim(T1C1, **T3C1**), sim(T1C1, **T3C2**), sim(T1C3,**T3C3**)

So, how can I calculate the similarity between two columns, **where the columns from the same table are ignored** (or just return 0 values) and I am working with Python.

Thank you.

```
# given the list:
tbl_name = ['User', 'Band', 'Hall']
col_name = ['User.ID', 'User.Name', 'User.Address', 'Band.ID', 'Band.Name', 'Band.Country', 'Hall.ID', 'Hall.Name', 'Hall.Address']
```

```
def jaro_distance():
      .....
  return jaro_distance

# calculate similarity
for x in col_name:
   for y in col_name:
       print(jaro_distance(x,y))
```

The above code, return all the combination from col_name.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a code probelm but an algorighm and mathmatic/stats issue.
Your question can be simplfied to : how to cacultate similarity between two columns.

1. For numerical variables, distance my be a way.
2. For categorial varaibles, you may need to find NLP relative solutions.